# Why didn't Sarutobi kill Danzo?

Tags: naruto

As I'm watching these filler episodes, I am wondering, why was Danzo still alive, after doing all the things he did to The Third? He hid a Wood style user, he tried to assassinate Sarutobi (not even once), he tried to lure the Anbu forces to join the Federation, he tried to manipulate the Hokage election after the death of Minato, and so on (just from these couple of episodes, without mentioning the whole "rivalry" between them).

The Third was aware of the situations, since he warned Danzo a lot of times. So even if he was a member of the Hokage's council, why did Sarutobi endure the disrespect and danger that came from Danzo? I would've been pleased even with a ban from the Village, but given what he had done, Sarutobi could've eliminated Danzo without any efforts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Danzo was, in his own way, protecting the Hidden Leaf.

Danzo would normally do the "dirty work" and handle with that "black ops" of the Hidden Leaf, thus keeping the village officials clean.

They had their disagreements, and yes Danzo did act in order to dispose of the Third and have control over the Hidden Leaf, but Hiruzen always believed that all he's doing was for the best of the village, so he let it slide.

Comment: also hiruzen is shown to have a very soft side. Even after he found out the evil doings of Orochimaru, he did not attempt to kill him.

Comment: @debal - That was more because Orochimaru was his student and he couldn't come to terms on killing his own student. The softness part only had a little effect in this specific case.

Comment: @RJ and Danzo was his team mate

Comment: but then we can safely assume, that in the end, practically Danzo caused Sarutobi's end..

Answer (score 0):

Danzo had Shisui's Kotoamatsukami. He also had Hashirama's cells, which enabled him to use the jutsu to his advantage with regeneration. So there is a possibility that even if Hiruzen wanted to kill him, Danzo could have used Kotoamatsukami to manipulate the Third's thoughts about him.

Comment: i doubt God of shinobi who lead countless uchiha can be manipulated by non uchiha sharingan user.

Comment: @NamikazeSheena huh? What does being an Uchiha have anything to do with it? Danzo was in Sarutobi's close circle. Plus, he had access to multiple Sharingan and had above average knowledge about them. Thats power. And about `manipulated by non uchiha ..`, Kotoamatsukami isnt your everyday manipulation trick.

Answer (score 0):

Sarutobi is a very uderstanding man, he probably just figured he'd give Danzo the benifit of a doubt, thinking that age would give him wisdom and he'd see that he was wrong,

too bad that never happened