# Does Danzo use a curse mark?

Tags: naruto

I totally understand what the Curse Mark is about, but I never knew that Danzo uses them like Orochimaru does. Not until some of the more recent episodes. I didn't even know The Foundation had access to such jutsu.

I always thought that the Curse Mark was something that only Orochimaru uses, and that Danzo used a "Sealing Jutsu" on Foundation Members. So who actually created the Curse Mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curse mark is Made by Orochimaru, it is also known as Orochimaru's Juinjutsu.

> Not having a body strong enough to handle this art, Orochimaru was unable to use Sage Mode and thus had to create an alternative way to make use of senjutsu. Orochumaru thus used Jūgo, whose body naturally produces an enzyme that triggers bodily transformations, and created a brand of cursed seals that would feed off the wielder's chakra and give them Orochimaru's senjutsu chakra

As you most likely have or will noticed, as is revealed in the story later on that orochimaru and Danzo work pretty close together.

**Edit:**
*the cursed seal used by Danzo is not the one that was created by Orochimaru, in fact he uses his own version.*

You pretty much answered to your own question here partially *in fact he uses his own version.* The root paralysis Juinjutsu is most likely a derived jutsu from the original curse mark made by Orochimaru. Now why would it most likely be a derived jutsu instead of a original created jutsu?

Almost all, if not all of the [Juinjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Special%3aSearchByProperty/Jutsu-20classification/Juinjutsu) are [Kinjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kinjutsu), Altough there is no direct punishment for using. The research on it has been banned due to the vile nature of the techniques. As Orochimaru wants to learn all the jutsu that exist he also learned and created tons of kinjutsu. And off course his experiments where not always flawless. There for the Root Paralysis is either a adapted failure or even a failure to begin with.

Altough as of right now it the origins have not been confirmed. But this is one of the highest plausible scenario's. We can almost 100% certain say that most Juinjutsu would not exist without Orochimaru to begin with, and this one most likely is not exception to that rule.

Comment: That I have noticed, another part of it that bugs me is doesn't that mean Donzo is guilty and the Third Hokage can tie them together like he already did? Donzo does need to be "executed".

Comment: @Traven Thats a whole other question (which already pretty much got answerd)   [Why doesent sarutobi kill danzo](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8202/why-didnt-sarutobi-kill-danzo) Btw it is in fact Danzo. Not Donzo, Using the wrong name might confuse people

Comment: I disagree, the cursed seal used by Danzo is not the one that was created by Orochimaru, infact he uses his own version. No where in the series it is mentioned that Danzo uses the same cursed seal as Orochimaru, and Danzo's own cursed mark has been show cased a number of times, during his battle with Sasuke, sai mentions it once, and in the anime Yamato mentions of it

Comment: @debal Ill ellaborate further on that in my answer in a bit.

Comment: @Dimitrimx I disagree with the last part stating that most Juinjutsu would not exist without Orochimaru... There is no evidence that supports that speculation. The Hyuga Clan too uses a Juinjutsu and that existed since the starting of the clan long before Orichimaru was even born. Its a complete speculation that Orochimaru developed the Root Curse Seal for Danzo.\

Answer (score 2):

The curse mark that you are referring to in context to Danzo is the [Root Paralysis Juinjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Danz%C5%8D%27s_Juinjutsu) which members of the root term it as "curse mark". It does not refer to the same curse mark that Orochimaru uses.

> This cursed seal is given to all members of the Anbu subgroup Root by
> Danzō Shimura, to ensure no information about Danzō or the
> organisation falls into the wrong hands. After Danzō died, the seals
> disappeared from all the Root members.
>
> When the wearer of this cursed seal speaks about anything
> incriminating related to Danzō or Root, their entire body will be
> paralysed, taking away their ability to speak or move. It is applied
> to the tongue and takes the shape of three solid lines and two broken
> lines from the back of the tongue to the tip.
>
> The seal can also be applied during combat, and can secretly be placed
> on the opponent's body. When the user activates it, the curse seal's
> marks spread around the opponent's body, paralysing them. However, one
> can break free from the seal with a strong enough release of chakra.

[image]

---

Sai had mentioned about it,

> Sai said that he could not, as the cursed seal Danzō had placed on
> his tongue prevented him from revealing anything about Root. Sakura
> remarked it was cruel, but Sai explained that it was for the best
> since Root had done a number of questionable things to protect the
> village.

[Source](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sai)

---

The curse mark that Orochimaru uses is called [Orochimaru's Juinjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Orochimaru%27s_Juinjutsu).

> Orochimaru's Juinjutsu are the cursed seals that were an often-used
> technique of Orochimaru in the series.

---

So as to the question `Does Danzo use a curse mark` the answer is yes, its called the Root Paralysis Jutsu.

And to the question `who actually created the cursed mark` the answer is, both Orochimaru and Danzo created their own cursed seals.